# check if registered sidebar is active & has widget content

Tags: widgets

I'd like to check if a registered sidebar has widget content - but can't seem to find a WP function for this - is_active_widget checks if it has content, but not if it exists or not.

```
function ql_widget( $widget, $widget_name, $element = 'sider' ){

    if ( $widget ) { // widget name passed ##

        // check if widget is active - return html & widget content if true ##
        if ( is_active_sidebar( $widget ) ) { 

        echo '
        <div class="'.$element.'">';

            dynamic_sidebar( $widget );

         echo '</div>';

        } else {

            // issue error if requested widget does not exist or is empty ##
            if ( ql_user_is_administator() ) { // user is admin ##

                if ( dynamic_sidebar( $widget ) ) { // empty ##

                    $message = 'empty';

                } else { // widget ID or name wrong ##

                    $message = 'error';

                }

?>
                <div class="error"><strong>Widget <?php echo $message; ?>:</strong> 
                <?php echo $widget_name ? $widget_name : $widget ; ?></div>
<?php 


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call this on the page using:

```
// load widget ##
// widget_id, widget name, class of containing element ##
ql_widget( 'sidebar-general', 'Standard Sidebar', 'sider' );
```

The sidebars are registered correctly with register_sidebar() and have an unique ID assigned to each.

currently this function returns the error to the admin if the widget is missing or empty - I'd like to be able to tailor the error to indicate if it's missing or empty

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
here's the working function:
[link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XXij2ePM)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wp_get_sidebars_widgets();` will return a list of all sidebars & the widgets in each of them. This can allow you to check for sidebars with no widgets

Comment: bingo! - I'll update the answer to show the solution I've used - thanks

Comment: Isn't that what `is_dynamic_sidebar` is for?

Comment: this allowed me to check all 3 states - wrong name, empty, display it if all is good...

Answer (score 10):

You can check if a sidebar is active and in use (contains widgets with content) through using [`is_active_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar), here's an example...

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( $sidebar ) ) {
    // Display some text
} else {
    // Display none
};
```

Where `$sidebar` is either the name, ID or number of the sidebar you wish to check.

#### Update:

Here's a suggestion for improving your function's legibility,

```
function ql_widget( $widget, $widget_name, $element = 'sider' ){

    if ( $widget ) { 

        $message = (ql_user_is_administator() ? 'empty' : 'error');
        $widget_name = ($widget_name ? $widget_name : $widget);

        if ( is_active_sidebar( $widget ) ) { 

            $html  = '<div class="'.$element.'">';
            $html .= dynamic_sidebar( $widget );
            $html .= '</div>';
            echo $html;

        } else {

            $html  = '<div class="error"><strong>Widget ';
            $html .= $message;
            $html .= '</strong> ';
            $html .= $widget_name;
            $html .= '</div>';
            echo $html;

        }
    }
} // This is the end of the function
```

And if you only want the error message to appear if admin, then wrap  the inner contents of the `else` statement with another conditional or change the `else` to `elseif` and run the check for an administrator and optionally finish off with an `else` condition to meet all other outcomes, such as for regular users.
Codex reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar

Comment: thanks - I already am using that function - I want to display the sidebar if it has widgets, return an error if the sidebar is named wrong and do nothing if it's named correctly but empty.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer I solved my problem with this function, hope it helps, and thanks, Mridul Aggarwal.

```
function is_active_sidebar_with_content( $sidebar ) {

   $sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

   if ( isset( $sidebars[ $sidebar ] ) && ! empty( $sidebars[ $sidebar] ) ) {
       return true;
   }


   return false;
}
```