# How to determine if the sidebar is empty? Or not active?

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

I used `is_sidebar_active('NameOfSidebar')`, but it seems not working. It returns false all the time. I wanna have a condition that goes like this

```
if('sidebar is not active'){
 //must not display the section title.
}else{
 //display the sidebar here..
}
```

Comment: Are there any widgets in that particular sidebar area? If not, then it will return false.

Comment: Yes, there is. I used post meta video widget. Though I didn't add video for certain page, the video section is still showing. I'll try is_active_sidebar and see if it works

Comment: Per the answers below you seem to have mis-typed the function name. `is_sidebar_active()` does not exist. I am surprised that you didn't get an error.

Comment: I just mistyped it here, I used is_active_sidebar on my code. sorry for that.

Comment: Then maybe you have the ID wrong? That is the correct function for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69527/check-if-registered-sidebar-is-active-has-widget-content

Answer (score 4):

Try [`is_active_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar)

```
if ( is_active_sidebar('your-sidebar-i.d'))
```

Where your-sidebar-i.d equals the I.D you use when you register the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a not (!) in your conditional.

```
if (!is_active_sidebar('NameOfSidebar')){
    // Must not display the section title.
} else {
    // Display the sidebar here.
}
```

The first condition will return true if is_active_sidebar() returns false. is_active_sidebar() returns false if that sidebar has no active widgets saved to it.

Comment: This is accurate, no idea why people are down-voting this...

Answer (score 0):

This snippet checks all widgets in an area e.g. sidebar:

```
function count_widgets_in_area($area) {
    $widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
    if(isset($widgets[$area])) {
        return count($widgets[$area]);
    }
    return null;
}

if(!is_null(count_widgets_in_area("area_id"))) {
  // there are some widgets 
} else {
  // widget area is empty
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/pankamilr/20ba1791fe7dac4c6291